# iOS application authorization to Facebook Workplace

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-workplace

I'm making an iOS application, that needs integration with Facebook Workplace for users can manage their private data (messages, posts, etc).

As I understand I need an app inside admin panel to be created, set up permissions for it, generate app access token for API calls.

With the token we can fetch information about groups and members existing in community. We can fetch information about specific member groups with member access token (impersonate token), which we can get with user id.

We need an authorization to get the user id. We can login to Facebook with iOS SDK, but facebook login and facebook workplace login are two different entities. I couldn't find anything about authorization in Facebook Workplace.

Is it possible at all? I think it should be, because this page exists and all API calls require some code and token that had to be somehow retrieved previously: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/account-management-api

Comment: This isn’t supposed to be used with user-specific access token in the first place. If you want your actual workplace members to be able to make any changes to their account details - then you still need to use your general workplace API token that you got in the step of creating your app.

Comment: Yeah, but anyway I need to which user should be modified and that's why I need authentication. As I see it the flow should be like this:
User logins with his workplace login and password -> api returns information about the user including his id -> we can fetch any user specific information from api with the user id.

Comment: I don’t think things are supposed to work that way. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api#accesstoken - even the “member access token” is something that needs the app access token in the first place to fetch it. I can’t find anything in the docs about a user login that would result in a specific access token for that user.